# i have 2 unique constraints, how do i identify which one was violated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, oracle, node-oracledb

In a table I have 2 unique keys: one for **EMAIL** `column, and the other for **PHONE NUMBER** column.

When I get an error because of ORA-00001 (unique constraint violated), I want to know which key has been violated.

As an example, when I `console.log()` the error it gives me something like this:

```
[Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (E_GO_APP_DATABASE.E_GO_APP_USERS_UK2) violated] {
  errorNum: 1,
  offset: 0
}
```

But when I work with it, I can only work with this:

```
{
  errorNum: 1,
  offset: 0
}
```

I can also make it with other SQL requests, but I would like to know if it is possible to know which unique key has been violated.

Code:

```js
            var error = await signup.create(user);
            if(!error) {
                res.status(201).json({
                    success: true
                });
            } else if(error.errorNum == 1) {
                console.log(error);
                res.status(401).json({
                    success: false,
                    error: error
                });
            }
```

Comment: off the top of my head: use `try`-`catch`.  show your code...

Comment: If you only have the errorNum and offset values then you can't figure it out from those. When/where/why is the message part you showed discarded?

Comment: @iAmOren here is my code

Comment: @AlexPoole I do not know. i put my code in the question.

Comment: Is that exactly what the console log shows? And the ORA error isn't being logged separately, by `signup.create`? I don't see how that can be constructed such that `error.errorNum` is valid. Can you check the type of the error variable, or get more information about what the create calls is supposed to return?

Answer (score 1):

Check in `user_cons_columns` or `all_cons_columns`:

```
select column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name = 'E_GO_APP_USERS_UK2'
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=820fba2d7276ea617db71c8375512746)</sup>**

Comment: I guess I can do that, but I have other problem. I cannot take that **UK2** from the error. This is my problem. I do not know how.

Comment: Sorry, I can help you only in Oracle part of your question.